# Trying to subscribe to a collectionusing react-meteor-hooks but loading is always true

Tags: meteor, react-hooks, publish-subscribe, meteor-react

Trying to implement 'react-meteor-hooks, but 'loading' variable is always true:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSubscription, useMongoFetch } from 'react-meteor-hooks';
import { Comments } from '../../../../collections/comments';

export const GiveComments = (props) => {

     const loading = useSubscription('getComments');

    if (loading) {
         console.log('loading... ');
    } else {
        const allComments = useMongoFetch(Comments.find({}));
        console.log('loaded: ', allComments);
      }
    return (null);
};
```

Publishing:

```
  Meteor.publish('getComments', function() {
    return Comments.find({});
  });
```

These hooks looks amazing, but can't get it to work. Why 'loading' does not stop?

Comment: Your code looks ok, but perhaps the publish function isn't getting called?

Comment: I tested it, publishing is ok. :-/

Comment: Must be a bug then? How did you test it?